# If $X \times X \simeq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $X \simeq \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, products

I came across this question few years ago, but I have not yet reached a satisfactory answer.

If a product of a topological space $X$ with itself is homeomorphic to the real plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, must $X$ be homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb{R}$? Here I am not assuming a priori that $X$ is a manifold.

Comment: Sure $X$ is of cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$, connected, second countable, and so on. Can we elaborate more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that I am not an expert in this, but I think this paper is what you are looking for:

[Non-manifold factors of Euclidean spaces](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm68/fm68116.pdf), Fund. Math. 68 (1970), 159–177, MR275396 describes classes $\Gamma_m$ and $\Gamma_n$ where if $X \in \Gamma_m$ and $Y \in \Gamma_n$, then $X \times Y \cong \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

Comment: Duh, this is an unexpected surprise to me. Thanks for the great reference!

Comment: I don't like this answer because it spoils my efforts for a planned simple proof that the claim is *of course* true. :)

Comment: There is no $X$ such that $X^3 \simeq \Bbb R^2$. So we can show some things. It's not all weird.